# rgl.snapshot() No Longer Works

Tags: r, rgl

I just upgraded R and rgl to the following versions.    Now, rgl.snapshot() no longer works.   It worked in previous versions.   Is there a way around this?

R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
rgl version 0.92.798

```
> library(rgl)   
> x<-rnorm(100)   
> y<-rnorm(100)   
> z<-rnorm(100)   
> r<-0.2   
> p <- plot3d(x, y, z, axes=FALSE, box=FALSE, radius=r, type='s',    
  + xlab="", ylab="", zlab="", col=rainbow(100))   
> rgl.snapshot("C:\\Temp\\pic.png", fmt="png", top=TRUE )    

Error in rgl.snapshot("C:\\Temp\\pic.png") :     
pixmap save format not supported in this build
```

Comment: Hmmm. It worked on my machine, but I was only using rgl_0.92.794.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That build doesn't have PNG support (yet). You can use `postscript` instead:

http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/rgl/html/postscript.html

Comment: Evan, when I use rgl.postscript, it provides a vector image.  Using .pdf format this little 100 data point picture is 1.3MB.    With some of my data, that can easily exceed 100MB.    That's why I need a bitmap image.   Have the maintainers posted a date for the next rgl update?

Comment: I don't know. I have read that they are "working on it" via mail archives. Would it be possible to rollback to 0.92.794 (or earlier)?

Comment: Evan, I'm willing to try just about anything.    How do you install earlier versions?

Comment: Use an older version from the download site: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html

Comment: Well, I removed the 0.92.798 version and installed the 0.92.794 version.   I ran the above code again (and several other programs) and got the same error message.   I tried other ways to get around this problem, but it looks like I'm stuck.   I'm going to drop rgl.   Thanks for your help, Evan and DWin.