# How to preserve scale of rotated lattice cloud scatter plot?

Tags: r, animation, lattice

Background: I am trying to animate a rotating 3D scatter plot using R's lattice::cloud() function. I create a sequence of PNG images in R, then create an animated GIF from the sequence.

The problem is that the scale of the plot changes with rotation so the animated cube appears to grow and shrink as it turns.

Here is an example using just two plots (based on one of the cloud examples):

```
library(lattice)
par.set <-
  list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"),
     clip = list(panel = "off"))

print(cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, 
    data = iris, cex = .8, 
    groups = Species, 
    screen = list(z = 0, x = 0, y = 0),
    par.settings = par.set,
    scales = list(col = "black")),
  split = c(1,1,2,1), more = TRUE)
print(cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width,
    data = iris, cex = .8, 
    groups = Species,
    screen = list(z = 0, x = 0, y = 30),
    par.settings = par.set,
    scales = list(col = "black")),
  split = c(2,1,2,1))
```

I would like the right-hand plot to appear the same size as the left-hand plot. In this example it is quite a bit smaller. I don't have to use R or lattice::cloud() but it is very close to what I want...

Trying rgl, it looks like maybe my copy of rgl is incompatible with my version of R. I'll upgrade R when I have a minute:

```
> library(rgl)
> df <- data.frame(x=runif(10,0,1), y=runif(10,0,1), z=runif(10,0,1), color=round(runif(10,1,3)))
> plot3d(df$x, df$y, df$z, col=df$color, size=2, type='s')
> rgl.snapshot("C:\\pic.png", fmt="png", top=TRUE )
[1] "failed"
Warning messages:
1: In rgl.snapshot("C:\\pic.png", fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
  RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.2.40
2: In rgl.snapshot("C:\\pic.png", fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
  RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.4.1
3: In rgl.snapshot("C:\\pic.png", fmt = "png", top = TRUE) :
  RGL: PNG Pixmap Saver Warning: Incompatible libpng version in application and library

> sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.92.798

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.11.1
```

I updated to R 2.12.2 and now this works (using GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick):

```
open3d()
with(iris, plot3d(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, col=Species))
movie3d(spin3d(), duration=12, dir="C:\\Movie", convert=FALSE)
system('"C:\\program files\\graphicsmagick-1.3.7-q8\\gm.exe" convert -delay 12 C:\\Movie\\movie*.png C:\\Movie\\animate.gif')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the rgl package, this is how I approached the same phenomea

```
require ("rgl")

df <- data.frame(x=runif(10,0,1), y=runif(10,0,1), z=runif(10,0,1), color=round(runif(10,1,3)))

plot3d(df$x, df$y, df$z, col=df$color, size=2, type='s')

?movie3d()

demo(flag)

test <- spin3d(rpm=6,axis=c(0,0,1))
?spin3d

open3d()
plot3d(oh3d(col="lightblue", alpha=0.5))
play3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=20), duration=3)


open3d()
plot3d( cube3d(col="green") )
M <- par3d("userMatrix")
play3d( par3dinterp( userMatrix=list(M,
                                 rotate3d(M, pi/2, 1, 0, 0),
                                 rotate3d(M, pi/2, 0, 1, 0) ) ), 
    duration=4 )

movie3d( spin3d(), duration=5 )
```

My session info for a confirmed working example.

```
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgl_0.92.798

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.12.2
```

Comment: @OneWhoIsUnnamed This looks promising but for some reason movie3d() is unable to create the output files. It creates empty png files for each frame and logs an error like `Writing movie115.png 
[1] "failed"`.

Comment: Also plot3d() doesn't seem to have the same level of control over appearance as cloud(). How can I change the default window size and the size of the axis labels? Thanks!

Comment: @Kent Johnson  I'm not sure why movie3d() fails for you, the above works without error on my machine, but granted is not exactly what you were looking for but an illustrative example.  To troubleshoot can you please post the output of sessionInfo()?  Perhaps this is an R version issue.  Also is it possible to post a minimal command example that you used to get this error? It would be useful for me to try to replicate this error.

Comment: @OneWho: Several of us have problems with rgl.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543272/rgl-snapshot-no-longer-works

Comment: I've posted my session info for a confirmed example.  I think this can be solved!  Let's work together to get this working!!

Comment: @OneWho: I think the problem depends on your graphics card/drivers. rgl worked fine (provided more than just a screen view) until I upgraded R and rgl. That's when the "...pixmap save format not supported in this build..." errors started happening.  I e-mailed the maintainer, but all I could do was to try to get older rgl versions to work (they didn't).